# Strange issue with PHP include

Tags: php, include

I am using XAMPP for PHP development, new to this, was previously familiar with WampServer. I have a require_once statement like this

```
require_once('config.php');
```

I assumed it would include the file in the current directory, but it is fetching a file from PEAR directory because the path to PEAR is also set in the include_path directive in php.ini.

However if I change the include_path to just '.' which is the current directory, it seems to work fine.

This had worked fine for me before in WampServer, no clue as to what causes this (it has always looked in the current directory before fetching form include paths). Is this a problem with PHP or something to do with XAMPP? And any solutions for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you already found the problem: the include path directive is different.

Every `include` is looked up *relative to the include path*, the first matching file is used. If you want to explicitly use a file in a specific directory, use an absolute path:

```
require_once __DIR__ . '/config.php';
```

Comment: I tried that already, that does not work. Only thing that works for me is to wither set the include_path to only `.` in the php.ini, or call `set_include_path('.')` just before the require_once statement.
I am wondering why it does not look in the current directory for a file before looking it in included paths!

Comment: I just checked echoing `__DIR__` and it ouputs the correct directory where the file is. Still the file is being fetched from another folder even if I specify `__DIR__ . '/config.php'`!!